# Concrete class as generic param

Tags: java, generics

Is there any difference between those definitions?

```
 public class Foo<String> {}
 public class Foo{}
```

**UPDATED**
Can first one have any real usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the first is equivalent to `Foo<T>` but with the type parameter named `String` (which is *not* `java.lang.String`) instead of `T`. So you aren't actually using a concrete class as the type parameter (that isn't legal... try changing the declaration to `class Foo<java.lang.String>`).

Comment: Thanks. I just wondered does first definition can have any real usage?

Comment: @Stas: Like I said, you can use the first just the same as you could use the definition `Foo<T>`, since `String` doesn't mean the class `String` in that context. I strongly recommend you _not_ do that though! =)

Comment: Thanks a lot. There should be way to wrap this stuff to joke.